# GNU make: detect target creation vs. update

Tags: gnu-make

Is there a way in GNU make to detect whether the target needs to be created resp. updated?

I need this differentiation due to a oddity of MS lib.exe (which I have to use).

UN*X-like tools support "ar cr lib.a file.o" either creating or updating "lib.a". Unfortunately MS lib.exe requires this:

> 1st call     : lib.exe -out:lib.lib file.obj
> next call(s) :
> lib.exe -out:lib.lib **lib.lib** file.obj

So I have 2 different commands with target and dependencies being the same...

> lib.lib : file.obj   lib.exe -out:$@ $^       <-- if lib.lib not exist
>
> resp.
>
> lib.exe -out:$@ **$@** $^    <-- if lib.lib exist

I want this to be handled by GNU make and not delegate it to the command (aka shell).

NB: double-colon rules actually won't help as the problem is burried in an implicit rule
(%.obj) : %.obj
$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) -out:$@ $@ $^

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do it but you can write your rule to do it:

```
lib.lib: file.obj
        lib.exe -out:$@ $(if $(wildcard $@),$@) $^
```